# I am getting en error for the misplaced return statement while retriving the values for a particular ssnum from the mysql database

Tags: java, jdbc

```
public Customer getCustomer(String ssNum) throws CustomerHomeException, ClassNotFoundException {
  String query = "Select ssn, customer_name from customer ";
  ResultSet rs = smt.executeQuery(query);
  Customer customer = null;
  while (rs.next()) {
    if (ssNum.equals(rs.getString("ssn"))) {
      customer = new Customer(rs.getString("ssn"), rs.getString("customer_name"));
    }
    return customer;
  }
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new CustomerHomeException("Failed to create CustomerHome", e);
  }
}
```

I'm getting an error for the `return` statement placed while retriving the value from the **MySQL** database. Value already exists.

Comment: Say you don't find something and you exit the `while`, what is your code supposed to do?

Comment: So this isn't proper code, the parenthesis aren't matching up.  As for the error, are you sure the record doesnt already exists?

Comment: the code should match the given ssnum in the if loop, I used while to iterate through all the record in the database.the record already exists

Comment: yes the ssn is varchar in db, here i use it as string

Answer (score 0):

Method `getCustomer` expecting to `return customer` at the end of function definition. and you are returning in the middle of `while` loop. So Compiler complaining to add or place return statement as your method suppose to, because its not always happening that `while` or `if` will get executed every time.

```
private static int hello() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: the code is throwing SQL exception after the if loop,if loop works fine.

Comment: @user2382753 What is the `excpetion`. Add it to your OP.

Comment: i have to either return the object reference or pass null to the function. I want to place the return statement accordingly

Comment: @user2382753 Yes you are correct. But always make sure that you check for `null` and deal with it to avoid `NPE` as your method returns `null`.